# What is an algorithm for estimating a given shape using a polygon with N vertices?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, polygon

I have a random shape.  I want to turn it into a polygon with N vertices.  Is there an algorithm that chooses the best N vertices to estimate a given shape?

For example, I have this shape:

[image: shape]

Given an N, say 20, what is the algorithm to choose 20 points along the perimeter of this shape to generate a best-fit polygon?

Something like this:

[image: shape2] [image: shape3]

Comment: You need to say how the curve is expressed and how you define "good."  There is a simple greedy algorithm for "thinning" a curve drawn as pixels on a raster into a subset of the pixels that are now the vertices of line segments. Here the "goodness" is minimal number of original pixels to obtain a ceiling deviation distance from the original curve by the new line segments.  Is that of interest?

Comment: Yup, that's pretty much what I'm looking for.  In the simplest form, I'm given an image that has a random shape on it and I have to turn the shape into a polygon using a pre-set number of vertices (or less).

Comment: The thinning algorithm however will put all the lines representing convex areas inside the actual line and all those in concave areas outside.  That's not the "best" polygon by many definitions of "best."  It still meets your requirements?

Comment: Yes, I believe that would work--I'd have to try it out and make sure, but it sounds fine.  The biggest key here is reducing the shape to N number of points (vertices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thinning algorithm we discussed in comments works on a curved polyline, which is usually a chain of pixel coordinates, but doesn't have to be.  It eliminates points that are "unnecessary" to render the curve within some given tolerance.   Let `P_0` and `P_n-1` be the polyline end points and `Eps` be the tolerance.  We will produce a subsequence of these points as follows:

```
function thin(P, I, J)
  return [] if J <= I + 1
  let P_k, I < k < J be a point at farthest 
      distance D from line through P_I and P_J
  return [] if D <= Eps
  return thin(P, I, k) | [P_k] | thin(P, k, J)
```

The result is then `[P_0] | thin(P, 0, n-1) | [P_n-1]`.

The distance calculation is standard stuff.  `dist(P, A, B)` of `P` from line through `A` and `B` is `abs(unitperp(B - A) dot (P - A))`.  In turn, `perp(v) = [-v_y, v_x]`, `unit(v) = v / sqrt(v dot v)`, finally `unitperp(v) = unit(perp(v))`.  Of course in the real calculation you want to compare distance squared rather than actual distance to avoid square root calculations for a bit of speed advantage.

You have a closed polygon, so you'll have pick any point Q as both P_0 and P_N with the rest between.  The result will be either `[Q] | thin(P, 0, n-1)` or just `thin(P, 0, n-1)` depending on whether `Q` is farther than `Eps` from the line between the end points of `thin(P, 0, n-1)` or not.

Answer (score 4):

There is a considerable literature on the topic, which goes under the key phrase
*polygonal chain approximation*.
Here is an early work, whose [subsequent 111 citations](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=2051513941166255941&as_sdt=40000005&sciodt=0,22&hl=en)
may be of more use than the original:

> Melkman, A. and O'Rourke, J.,
>   "On polygonal chain approximation,"
>   in [Computational Morphology](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/bimj.4710310809/abstract), Ed. G.T. Toussaint,
>   Elsevier, North-Holland, 1988: 87-95.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Douglas-Peucker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) algorithm for polyline simplification.

It has best case O(N Log N) behavior, and (unfortunately) O(N²) in the worst case. There is a more complex variant called DPHull, with a guaranteed O(N Log N) worst case. See "Speeding Up the Douglas-Peucker Line-Simplication Algorithm" by Hershberger & Snoeyink.